# Just an Easy Python Replace() Function

Tags: python, replace

I am a beginner with Python try to play with a replace function, and came across this problem:

```
quote="Inquiring the application issues"
t=quote.title()        
print(t)                #prints "Inquiring the Application Issues"        
t=t.replace("the","a")  #try to replace "the" to "a" in the title-formatted quote
print(t)               #still prints "Inquiring the Application Issues", "the" didn't get replaced
```

Can anyone point out the my problem here? Many thanks!

Comment: If you look at the *actual* thing printed in your first `print`, the problem is rather obvious.

Comment: `title()` also capitalizes `the` into `The` (at least on my Python 3.4.3). Therefore, trying to replace `the` afterwards does not work.

Comment: thanks guys, I already found my error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either the debugger or the interactive shell:

```
>>> quote="Inquiring the application issues"
>>> t=quote.title()
>>> print(t)
Inquiring The Application Issues
```

Note that `The != the`.

Comment: Yea, i wasn't careful enough. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @SimonLi Accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

print(t)   #prints "Inquiring the Application Issues"

Not prints  "Inquiring The Application Issues"?

Comment: I just found out that it actually prints "The", so apparently trying to replace "the" is not working :D, I was not careful enough. Thanks for the answer though